# CloudStack interaction with Public Cloud

Tags: apache-cloudstack, cloud-platform

I'm setting up a new Cloudstack infrastructure and haven't found much resources regarding one of my requirement:
I'm looking for a possibility to have my CloudStack environment, interacting with a Public-Cloud.
I'd like for example, to be able to replicate, migrate or clone one VM/Instance, from my private cloud, to a public cloud. I'd like to be able to create new VM to the public cloud should my infrastructure grow too quickly, and bring them back to my environment whenever possible.

This is easy to perform with SCVMM and Azure. But haven't found similar info about this for CloudStack.
Citrix’ Cloudplatform and I are both based on CloudStack and Xen Server, is there any possibility to build something with them?
Or with another public cloud provider?

Would be glad to hear some info on this topic,
Thanks in advance!